# launch my first android application

Tags: android, emulation

I am trying to launch my hello world application in emulator of android. But in Console I am getting the following error:

```
 [2012-06-18 16:55:50 - hello] Failed to find an AVD compatible with target 'Android 4.0.3'.
```

My project name is hello and package name is com.hello .
Please tell how to solve the issue and get inspire to to enter the world of Android.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Either Make a AVD for android 4.0.3 or set a Android version of your application which AVD you already have. Also use android:minSDKversion in manifest file.

Comment: Use `android:minSDKversion=7` in your manifest file. After, that you can run that app from android version 2.1 upto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an emulator that is the same target API as your application.

Now make a new AVD by going to Window > AVD Manager and then New. Make a new AVD who's target is the same as your applications "4.0.3" or API level 15.

Answer (score 0):

Above error indicated that you are developing on **Android 4.0.3** but your Android AVD is of lower version than Android 4.0.3.

Workaround 1:
Create/Edit AVD and specify **Platform** as **4.0.3**.

Workaround 2:
Change `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10"/>` in 'AndroidManifest.xml' and
`target=android-10` in `project.properties`.

NOTE: I've used API 10 just for example. You should use the API level which you have specified for your **AVD**.

Comment: after changing , I got the following error: [2012-06-18 18:42:11 - first] Unable to resolve target 'android-10'

Comment: you should have **Android sdk for API-10** installed.

Answer (score 0):

you are using a device or avd with an older android os, but your project seems to be configured for android 4.0.4

create an android virtual device with android 4.0.4 or set your project configuration to your devices (or avd) sdk level (or below)

Answer (score 0):

The emulator you are using is not compatible with the sdk version you mentioned in your manifest file.

If you have given :

```
     <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
```

then you need to install the sdk for 4.0.*

or you can change it in manifest:

```
      <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
```